# Select into is selecting last record when trying to generate dynamic update statement for each table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I have a table like below :

**Archival:**

```
TableName        ColumnName         Datatype           NewValue
Employee         FirstName          nvarchar           Abc
Employee         LastName           nvarchar           Pqr
Employee         Age                int                28
Address          City               nvarchar           Chicago
Address          StreetName         nvarchar           KKKKK
```

I am trying to create dynamic update statement for each table and want to execute update statement for each individual table and rollback if any update fails.

Expected update statement query for each individual table:

```
Update Employee set FirstName = 'Abc', LastName = 'Pqr', Age = 21 
where DepartmentId = 100;

Update Address set City = 'Chicago', StreetName = 'KKKKK'
where DepartmentId = 100;
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
Alter PROC [dbo].[UpdateDataByDeptID]
  @departmentId int
As
 Begin
       Declare db_cursor CURSOR for select TableName from Archival 
       group by TableName
       
       Declare @tableName nvarchar(50),
               @columnName nvarchar(50),
               @datatype nvarchar(50),
               @newValue nvarchar(50)

        open db_cursor
        Fetch Next from db_cursor into @tableName;
        While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        Begin
               select @columnName = ColumnName,
                      @datatype = Datatype,
                      @newValue = NewValue
               from Archival where TableName = @tableName;
               
               print @tableName + ' ' + @columnName + ' ' + @newValue
            Fetch Next from db_cursor into @tableName
        End;
        close db_cursor;
        DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
        
    Begin Transaction
        Begin Try
            --execute each of the update statement like below for ex:
            Update Employee .....
            Update Address .....
          Commit transaction
        End Try
        Begin Catch
          Rollback
        End Catch
    End
End -- end of SP
```

But the problem is this line :

```
print @tableName + ' ' + @columnName + ' ' + @newValue
```

Above line is giving me last record for each table. For example for `Employee` table :

```
Employee         Age                int                28
```

Hence I am not able to generate individual update statement for each table.

Final expected output is below for my transaction after each update statement for each individual table:

```
Begin Transaction
        Begin Try
            --execute each of the update statement like below for ex:
              Update Employee set FirstName = 'Abc', LastName = 'Pqr', Age = 21 
              where DepartmentId = 100;

              Update Address set City = 'Chicago', StreetName = 'KKKKK'
              where DepartmentId = 100;
          Commit transaction
        End Try
        Begin Catch
          Rollback
        End Catch
End
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: I think you should look into some examples using the keywords "dynamic SQL update sql server". There will be plenty of examples floating around detailing what you'd need to do. The gist of it is that you'd basically create a variable (e.g. `declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';`) and then modify it in a way such as `select @sql += 'UPDATE ' + quotename(tablename) + ' SET ' + quotename(columnname) + ' = ' + quotename(newvalue,'') + ' WHERE DepartmentId = 100;' FROM Archival;` or something similar that you could use if you needed all the columns in one update statement...

Comment: As for why your print only outputs the last row, that's because you're basically just reassigning the variables for each row until you reach the last row. If you have a table with a column called 'A' and values 'X', 'Y', 'Z' and you do something like `SELECT @variable = A FROM mytable` you're only going to get one of those values. You could do something like `SELECT @variable += A FROM mytable` and as long as @variable wasn't NULL it'll concatenate 'X', 'Y' and 'Z'. (But for what you're trying to achieve, this doesn't matter... It's just to help you understand what was happening.)

Comment: @ZLK How can I generate 1 update statement for each tables with list of columns inside the while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of how you could approach something like this is by using dynamic SQL.

For example:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

DECLARE @tablename NVARCHAR(255);

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT [TableName] FROM [Archival];

OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @tablename;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql += N'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + ' SET ';
    SELECT @sql += QUOTENAME([ColumnName]) + N' = ' + QUOTENAME([NewValue], '''') + N', '
    FROM [Archival]
    WHERE [TableName] = @tablename;
    SELECT @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 1, LEN(@sql) - 1) + N'
WHERE DepartmentId = 100;
';
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @tablename;
END
CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Which should give you something to your expected output, I believe.

I would be careful when doing something like this though if you can't trust what's in the NewValue column. (e.g. if it's possible for someone to put in some sort of malicious SQL that would be executed here).

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me. I will check tomorrow nd let you know. Once again thank you so much for your time and help

Comment: Datatype is varchar for “NewValue” column in “Archival” table. Now the problem is my update is failing for “Employee.Age” column because Age is an int datatype in Employee table. So how can I generate that casting logic in the update statement based on the Datatype in the Datatype column?

Comment: You could use a `CASE` expression if you needed to use different datatypes. e.g. `CASE WHEN [DataType] = 'Nvarchar' THEN QUOTENAME([NewValue], '''') WHEN [DataType] = 'Int' THEN [NewValue] END` and modify as appropriate for any other abnormalities.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and kind efforts towards helping me. Really really appreciated.